# Can't upload big RDF files to a fuseki dataset

Tags: fuseki

I downloaded [wordnet ontology](https://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/download/) and I want to upload its files (RDF files) to fuseki server.

I created a dataset successfully, but whenever I try to upload wordnet RDF files It gives me an error on some files (those big one's, such as `wordnet-glossary.rdf` which size is 21.7MB), Here's the error message I get:

[image: Error when uploading a big file to fuseki server]

How to solve this problem?
Is there a better way to upload big files to fuseki server?

**NOTES:**

Some files are bigger than this one, but all of them are less than 100MB.

I set my dataset type to `Persistent` when I created it.

Comment: It's not the size of the files that is the issue. As the error message says there are too many XML entity expansions. The wordnet RDF/XML is using XML entities to declare the namespaces and they are referenced too many times in the files you are trying to upload for the parser to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html) `entityExpansionLimit`'s definition is:

> Limit the number of entity expansions.

It's default value is `64000`, and to make it unlimited, its value should be 0 or less.

The problem is that the `XML parser` is encountering more entities than its limit.

Passing `-DentityExpansionLimit=0` to the command that runs `fuseki server` solved the problem, Here's how it looks like:

```
java -Xmx1200M -jar -DentityExpansionLimit=0 fuseki-server.jar
```